# How do you declare a struct in a header file and define it in the .c file

Tags: c

I just need a simple direct answer to this, but I haven't been able to get any online.

Why do I get an error when I write the following in the `person.h` file:

```c
typedef struct Person Person_T;
```

And the following the the `person.c` file:

```c
typedef struct Person
{
  char *name;
  unsigned int age;
} Person_T;
```

EDIT: For reference, this is my `main.c` file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "person.h"

int main()
{
  Person_T sam = { "Sam", 24 };
  printf("%s, %d\n", sam.name, same.age);

  return 0;
}
```

And the error is `variable has incomplete type Person_T (aka 'struct Person')`

Two more related questions:

- Why do some people write something like `extern struct Person Person;` or something like that?
- When should I define my structs and functions in the header file, or rather go header-only in a library?

Sorry, I'm new.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate what you describe.

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry I thought that was an example. What's missing?

Comment: `Why do I get an error` what error? These are a few very broad questions, that are very hard to answer exactly. I do not think an answer will give you what you want... I would rather suggest to continue studying the C language. This is a bad forum to _learn_ programming, it's a great forum for ppl that already know programming to solve hard problems.

Comment: @KamilCuk `variable has incomplete type Person_T (aka 'struct Person')`

Comment: Then the answer is clear: `Why do I get an error` -> because the variable has incomplete type `Person_T`.

Comment: Update the question to include the error message

Comment: @KamilCuk Yeah that's why my main question is how do you declare a struct in the header and define it in the `.c` file. I'm not asking what the error is, I'm asking _why_ I'm getting it, like in, _what's wrong with my implementation_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main.c file which includes person.h, the type `struct Person` is declared but not defined.  Because of this, you can't create a variable of this type in main.c, although you *can* create a pointer to it.  In that case, person.c could contain functions that work on a `struct Person` and return a pointer to one so functions in other files don't need to know the details.

If you want this file and others to be able to use the fields of `struct Person`, you need to move the definition of the struct into the header file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there no way to leave my definition in my `.c` file? I've seen people use `extern` in their header files, but I have no idea how it works.

Comment: `extern` is used to declare a variable, not a type.  It's typically used to declare a variable in a header that multiple source files can use, with the definition of that variable in a singe source file.

Comment: so basically, my only option is to define the struct in the header file, if I don't want to mess up my code with `external variables`? Are C libraries always header-only because of this? Or are they not? Thank you!

Comment: struct definitions and `extern` variables have nothing to do with each other.  If you only want one source file to be able to know what's in `struct Person` and for other files to only be able to use a pointer to it, then you can keep the struct definition in the .c file.  If you want multiple files to be able to create and manipulate a struct of that type, the definition needs to be in the header.

Comment: Thank you! that's very well explained. Would you care before I accept your answer to show how a pointer to it would be written?

Comment: @XDarkDev It's called the "Opaque Pointer" or "Handle Pattern" or a bunch of other things (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer). I can only strongly recommend you get this answer working before even looking at that. It only has merit in things like Operating Systems and some very large systems. It's running before you're walking if you ask me.

Comment: @Persixty I just made it work. Going to post my answer. I'm really very comfortable working with such stuff, I was just really used to C++. Thank you for your answer, definitely checking out the article!

Comment: @Persixty in the article you've provided, int the C section, why is there no function to create the `obj` type? How do you create an instance of it?

Comment: @XDarkDev This story in C is the same story as C++. To declare a local variable the compiler needs to have seen its definition. 

I was assuming (by reputation) you were new to programming or cross-training from say Java where things are different (because it's Opaque Pointers to Objects throughout). In C++ it's called The Pimpl pattern. Over there it can be implemented with templates, but here in C you have to do it all by hand...

Comment: @XDarkDev The version in the Wiki expects the consumer code to allocate memory (`struct obj *o=(struct obj *)malloc(obj_size());` then `obj_setid(o,10)` then `free(obj);`. That's valid because it gives the consumer code more freedom. but it has downsides and not the most common style which usually provides `obj_create()` and `obj_delete()` functions that do (possibly..) `malloc() and `free()` for you or manage resources in some different way (like an OS which may have a pool of objects that it recycles).

Comment: @Persixty That is very well explained! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

In the header file:

```
typedef struct Person Person_T;
```

In the source file (without typedef!):

```
struct Person {
    char *name;
    unsigned int age;
};

int main()
{
    Person_T sam = { "Sam", 24 };
    printf("%s, %d\n", sam.name, same.age);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you want to declare a function in your header file, then you have to use a Pointer to Person_T, e.g.

```
int foo(Person_T *person);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This doesn't quite suit my goal right now, but definitely using it in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I just made it work.

I used @dbush's suggestion for it.

In my header file, I added all the functions necessary to interact with my structure:

```c
typedef struct Person Person_T;

Person_T* create_person(char *name, unsigned int age);

char* get_name(Person_T *person);
unsigned int get_age(Person_T *person);
```

Then implemented those in my `.c` file.

Finally, all I need to do is use these kind of *APIs* to interact with my `struct`. I feel that's the best design to ensure safety and elegance.

Comment: Congratulation, you've implemented Information hiding (aka Encapsulation) in C. That is exactly how it is done in C.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Thank You! It seems like a very elegant design for complex projects where safety is important. Never heard of it until I asked this question.